# How to display and store images from a server on the client side?

Tags: image, performance, reactjs, amazon-s3, react-redux

In my `React` app currently, I give the users an option to list an item with a maximum of 5 pictures they can pick. Upon clicking on the `Submit item` button I send those images to `S3` and store the returned `S3` urls into the database associated with that specific item.

My question is very general (I apologize for that) but when displaying the items on the `Item View` page, I retrieve the most recent 20 items and I take the items url's in the response and download the image from S3.

Is it ok to store the base64 version of that URL in the Redux store? Since I am having a hard time understanding how to cache the images. Since if the user navigates away from the `Item view` page and comes back I want to be able to grab the images from the Redux store rather than having to go redownload the image again from the internet.

Can someone point me on how to store downloaded images efficiently on the browser?

Comment: I think it will be a performance killer of client browser .

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI So would you recommend to just keep redownloading the images? I am assuming they will be cached but it will still take some time.

Comment: Hello @ToothyRel,   I put a clear answer.  look at it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Caching images in this way will overload browser memory.
- Also, downloading images frequently will cost you as you are using AWS S3.

Between two issues, you can solve your issue by :

- using **Cloudfront** as a distribution of this S3 bucket. Then you should build your client-side code to communicate with CloudFront endpoint instead of S3 endpoint.

Using Cloudfront will cache S3 content in edge locations for TTL. So when user requests an image, it will cost you only the first request until TTL expires .

Then ,  I recommend to keep downloading images and your redux `store` should save only images **links** . From deployment perpective,  you should  make  a wedding between  S3❤️ CloudFront.

You may need to look at [this type of articles](https://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2013/07/02/reduce-your-cloudfront-bills-with-cache-control/).

Comment: Oh okay got it. But since my user base is localized to the US, would using a service like Cloudfront be beneficial? Since Cloudfront would be useful when your user base is spread globally. Or does S3 not cache the images but cloudfront does instead and getting it front Cloudfront would be much cheaper than going to S3 everytime?